# How to handle file download popup using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written a code to download an excel file, it is working, but it stops as soon as the popup appears. Automatically it should download the file and store in specified location, which is not happening now. Please anyone help in finding a solution for this problem

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 


profile.setPreference("browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "text/csv"); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","e:\\SampleExcel"); 

driver.get("http://url");
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("abc");
driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("toolbar-link-admin-config")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Reports")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='5']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("edit-submit")).click();
```

Comment: Have you tried switching to that `popup` or `alert` or `window` which appears and accept it?

Comment: it is not needed to switch to alert in this file download popup rite

Answer (score 5):

Try below code

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        String path = "D:\\Downloads_sel";
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", path);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsksaveToDisk", "application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/excel,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/x-excel,application/x-msexcel");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

For complete MIME types list follow the link: http://qaautomationworld.blogspot.in/2014/02/file-downlaoding-using-selenium.html

Comment: Thanks HemaSundar, it works fine, even with Firefox Quantum !

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 

profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;"); 
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","e:\\SampleExcel");
```

Comment: it is not happening, same result as how it was before, forcefully i have to click on ok button to download

Comment: it is not a csv file, it is an excel with .xls extension

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `text` by `application` for preference setting of not prompting download dialog box, like following:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/csv");
```

Just for confirmation, the file which is downloaded is with `csv` extension, right? If it's not like that, we'll have to make change in above code.

Comment: it is an excel file, not csv file

Comment: What is its extenstion? .xl, .xls, .xlt or something?

Comment: Can you please answer my above comment?

Comment: Then try with `profile.setPreference("browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/excel");` or `profile.setPreference("browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/vnd.ms-excel");` or `profile.setPreference("browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/x-excel");` or `profile.setPreference("browser.helperapps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/x-msexcel");` If this works for you, let me know I'll update my answer with this one.

Comment: i will try and let u knw