# Popup window handle in Selenium Web Driver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a "File Export" link and when I click it, it is opening a new child window with options like "Open File","Save File" and OK or Cancel buttons. When I manually go through the steps and hit enter key it works and the file gets saved, but when I automate nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
 //Click Export link
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReportViewer1_ctl01_ctl05_ctl01")).Click();
 //Switch to popup window
 driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.Instance.WindowHandles.Last());
 //Click Enter to accept save option
 driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
 //Close child window
 driver.Close();
 //Switch back to Parent window
 driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.Instance.WindowHandles.First());
```

The problem is that the window is stuck in the parent window and I am not able to send "Enter" to the popup window

Answer (score 2):

Since, file download is not native to browser it is not possible to handle with `Selenium`. Remember, `Selenium` is only a tool to automate browser. However, you can handle this with setting up profile.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 

profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" , "application/octet-stream;application/csv;text/csv;application/vnd.ms-excel;"); 
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","e:\\SampleExcel");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466154/how-to-handle-file-download-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: When I try this method, i am getting exception browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting may not be overridden: frozen value=False requested value= False, so what I did is remove this profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false); from the code but still no luck I am still getting save as dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!
If anybody having issue to download file using selenium Webdriver, this is the solution.

```
    [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FileDownload()
    {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.joomla.org/download.html");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("latest")).Click();
        driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This can be done by using AutoIT Script