# Download file from sharepoint using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, sharepoint, selenium-webdriver, download

I am trying to download file from sharepoint url and written code to `neverask.savetodisk` but still it is showing dialog to save file. I tried same code and it works when we click download link from other URL but not working with sharepoint application. Here is code what i used...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

# To prevent download dialog
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder",'tt_at');
profile.set_preference("browser.download.lastDir",'tt_at');
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'tt_at')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir",True);
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "application/octet-stream,application/msexcel")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get("https://docs.ad.sys.com/sites/cloud/Project/Form/FolderCTID=0x01200069047C40C93C3846B74E0776AAD1610A&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EDocument&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence")  
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[8]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[4]/div[1]/a').click()
```

but this above code still showing dialog to select location.

Comment: Can you try adding this statement `profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);`? Also see this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466154/how-to-handle-file-download-popup-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution, try the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#Give Complete Path of download dir
profile.set_preference("browser.download.lastDir",r'd:\temp')
profile.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir",True)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk',"application/vnd.ms-excel,Content-Type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream")
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', "application/vnd.ms-excel,Content-Type=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/octet-stream")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.get("https://docs.ad.sys.com/sites/cloud/Project/Form/FolderCTID=0x01200069047C40C93C3846B74E0776AAD1610A&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EDocument&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence")  
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[8]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[4]/div[1]/a').click()
```

If this is also not working for you, do the following, install the addon [tamperdata](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) in firefox and observe the content type for the file you are trying to download and then add that exact text to "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.*" preference. That shall solve your problem!

[image]