# How can I get the embed data from PDFviewer page with C# or JS?

Tags: c#, selenium, http-headers, decode, pdf-viewer

I'm creating some test with selenium and C# .I have a window with PDF Viewer, I want to read the HTTP header of this window but the URL that is showing in the window is not what I'm supposed to use to get this data.

Honestly I don't really understand how is encoding and decoding this files. The thing that I want is read the filename to get the file then read it, and be sure that doesn't contain errors.

Some advises or links for understand better HTTP headers, metafiles, how enconde and decode pdf files etc.
 Here is some of my code

```
 URL url = new URL(driver.Url);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.toString());
    try
     { 
     HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     using (Stream rstream = res.GetResponseStream())
       {
         string fileName = res.Headers["Content-Disposition"] ;
        }
        res.Close();
      }
      catch{

      }
```

Comment: May be this answer shall help you get going http://stackoverflow.com/a/29828575/1437877

Comment: Can you rephrase this `I want to read the HTTP header of this window but the URL that is showing in the window is not what I'm supposed to use to get this data` statement?

Comment: I'm mean that I'm getting the driver.Url of the current window (PDF viewer), and I want to get the HTTP headers of that page but  the resource is not found with that URL.