# How to Save the the .msi file using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, testng-eclipse

I have to download the .msi file from the website using Selenium WebDriver. So I have written code for click on download button but I am not able to download the file file clicking Save button using Selenium WebDriver. It gives the download popup.

[image]

Comment: Use Robot class if you are using java

Comment: You may find this answer useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/29828575/1437877