# How to disable downloads popup using selenium web driver firefox profile?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

firefox profile using is :

```
protected FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile() {
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", path);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "text/csv,application/csv,application/text");
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv,application/csv,application/text");
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
    fxProfie.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    fxProfile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
}
```

(still i can see popup in browser) [image: here]

Initialising firefox driver with profile here:

```
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
ffBinary.setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(180));
internalDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, firefoxProfile());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle file download popup using Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466154/how-to-handle-file-download-popup-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @optimist_creeper pls find the attached image.. i'm concerned about the downloads info displayed in page

Comment: Try following property `fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown",false);` or `fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.animateNotifications", false)`

Comment: @Andersson tried both of them still not working...

Comment: Are you sure Firefox starts with this profile? Please show further code where you start browser and set profile.

Comment: @kotoj updated question..

Comment: Frankly speaking I have never used FirefoxBinary, so cant help you. It seems ok, 'showAlertOnComplete' should solve the problem

Comment: I have an idea, what version of selenium do you use?

Comment: using selenium version  2.53.1